# Why My Haskell Code is so slow compare to Swift and C

Tags: haskell

Here is very simple Haskell code to find all the Pythagoras integers from 1 to 200 that satisfied the Pythagoras Theorem X^2 = Y^2 + Z^2

Haskell:

```
let l = [1..200]
let pythagoras = [ x | x <- l, y <- l, z <- l, x^2 == y^2 + z^2]
```

It takes **24.1 seconds** to finish it,

Swift: 
Using standard for loop
**0.05 seconds**

C: 
Using standard for loop
**0.022 seconds**

[image]

Comment: This question is meaningless without at least including details on your compilation and execution.

Comment: Well perhaps you have to include the C and/or swift version of your test as well, since otherwise, it is quite meaningless.

Answer (score 8):

I measure the Haskell code running in `0.03 seconds`, leading me to believe you have ran this in the interpreter (which is for development, not performant execution) instead of compiling the code.  Also, you probably let the type default to Integer instead of using machine `Int` values.

```
tommd@HalfAndHalf /tmp% ghc -O2 t.hs && time ./t >/dev/null
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( t.hs, t.o )
Linking t ...
./t > /dev/null  0.03s user 0.00s system 87% cpu 0.040 total
tommd@HalfAndHalf /tmp% cat t.hs

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let l = [1..200] :: [Int]
  let pythagoras = [ x | x <- l, y <- l, z <- l, x^2 == y^2 + z^2]
  print pythagoras
```

Comment: Thanks to point that out, I'm new to Haskell

Comment: I can't see that code taking 24 seconds even in the interpreter. It just doesn't do that many iterations.

Comment: @Carl It takes about half that time on my box when I run it in GHCi. Maybe he just has a really slow computer.

Comment: Yep, my computer is Pentium 4E, it is pretty old computer and I'm very poor kid.